# Script-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using EF core migration  Visual Studio 2017 update 2 and latest asp.net core 1.1

My csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
```

I am able to run the command

```
Add-Migration
```

in my package manager console

However I am not able to run the command

```
Script-Migration
```

as I get the error message

> Script-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Try running this in Package Manager Console - `Get-Help EntityFramework` That would show you all EF commands available. In rare case, you may have ended up in incorrectly executed init script. Does uninstalling & re-installing the tools package help?

Comment: I ran it. It only shows 4 basic commands. Script-Migration is not part of the 4

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework Core Version 1.1.2.

Comment: Try this. Create new Console App, install EF tools package in it and run `Get-Help EntityFramework` if you see `Script-Migration` there then it will be project issue rather than machine issue.

Comment: yes its there. Must be a project issue then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading from Entity Framework Core 1.1. to Entity Framework Core 2.0 I can access the command.